# Can D&D 3.5 edition Class Defense Bonus and Armor as Damage Reduction rules be converted to 5e?

Tags: dnd-3.5e, dnd-5e, combat, house-rules, conversion

The D&D 3.5 edition supplement *Unearthed Arcana* offered optional rules for **Class Defense Bonus** and **Armor as Damage Reduction**.

Can I drop either or both rules directly into 5th edition without major disruption to balance and playability? Has anyone done this already?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I'm not sure that would work out very well.  5e treats armor and armor bonuses very differently than 3.5.  Because 5e uses a bounded scale for ACs and DCs, AC in 5e generally falls between 10 and 25, whereas in 3.5e you might see ACs climbing upwards of 30 at mid-tier levels.  If you make this change it greatly affects the difficulty by making every encounter easier for the PCs, who are now much harder to hit.  As for damage reduction, 5e doesn't have a "DR mechanic" in the same way as 3.5, and the methods of reducing damage taken are very limited compared to the relative ubiquity of DR as a stat in 3.5e.  I'm not sure exactly how you would translate armor as DR to 5e, except that it would also greatly upset the balance of the game.

**To answer your question directly, no, you could not drop either or both rules into 5e without majorly disrupting gameplay balance.**

Comment: Hmm, I wonder if just assigning Defense Bonus = Proficiency Bonus would work in a pinch? It makes sense on an intuitive level (your character's skill in both attacking and defending increases proportionately with level advancement). For monsters/NPCs, assign a Defense Bonus = To-hit modifier, so that Adjusted AC = 10 + Defense Bonus + armor bonus. This would draw out combats a bit, though.

Comment: Monsters gain a proficiency bonus based on their CR/XP value.  If you used the PB to add AC to your PCs, you might consider using it for your monsters also.  Then again, the net result is that all your ACs are higher and everything is harder to hit with no off-setting change to to-hit.

Comment: Yes, good point, some tweaking might be required.

Comment: @LegendaryDude Point taken, comment removed.

Comment: @KorvinStarmast I edited my answer anyway, to make it clear that there are ways to reduce damage taken in 5e but that they are not given the same treatment as DR the mechanic from 3.5e. :)

Comment: Checking 4th edition rules, AC = 10 + **1/2 your level** + armor bonuses + ability modifiers. So it seems WotC attempted to add a variant of the 3.5 defense bonus into the rules in 4th edition. As far as adding DB rules to 5th ed, maybe the better question is how to convert 4th ed AC to 5th ed AC?

Comment: @LegendaryDude Already a nice answer is even nicer.